# Control flow in Tensorflow 2 - gradients are None

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, control-flow

I have a Tensorflow 2.x model with the purpose of dynamically choosing a computational path. Here's a schematic drawing of this model:
[image]

The only trainable block is the Decision Module (DM), which is essentially a fully connected layer with a single binary output (0 or 1; It's differentiable using a technique called Improved Semantic Hashing). Nets A & B have the same network architecture.
In the training progress, I feed forward a batch of images until the output of the DM, and then process the decision image-by-image, directing each image to the decided net (A or B). The predictions are concatenated into a single tensor, who's used to evaluate the performance. Here's the training code (`sigma` is the output of the DM; `model` includes the feature extractor and the DM):

```
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')
train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='train_accuracy')


@tf.function
def train_step(images, labels):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # training=True is only needed if there are custom_layers with different
        # behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
        _, sigma = model(images, training=True)
        out = []
        for img, s in zip(images, sigma):
            if s == 0:
                o = binary_classifier_model_a(tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0), training=False)
            else:
                o = binary_classifier_model_b(tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0), training=False)
            out.append(o)

        predictions = tf.concat(out, axis=0)
        loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

    train_loss(loss)
    train_accuracy(labels, predictions)
```

The problem - when running this code, `gradients` returns `[None, None]`.
What I know for now is:

- The first part of the model (until the DM's output) is differentiable; I tested it by running only this section and applying a loss function (MSE) and then applying `tape.gradients` - I got actual gradients.
- I tried choosing a single (constant) net - e.g, net A - and simply multiplying it's output by s (which is either 0 or 1); This is performed instead of the `if-else` block in the code. In this case I also got gradients.

My concern is that such thing might not be possible - quoting from the [official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff#control_flow):

> ```
> x = tf.constant(1.0)
>
> v0 = tf.Variable(2.0)
> v1 = tf.Variable(2.0)
>
> with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
>   tape.watch(x)
>   if x > 0.0:
>     result = v0
>   else:
>     result = v1**2
> ```
>
> Depending on the value of x in the above example, the tape either
> records result = v0 or result = v1**2. **The gradient with respect to
> x is always None.**
>
> ```
> dx = tape.gradient(result, x)
> print(dx)
> >> None
> ```

I'm not 100% sure that this is my case, but I wanted to ask here for the experts' opinion.
Is what I'm trying to do possible? And if yes - what should I change in order for this to work?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly identified the issue. The control statement of the conditional is not differentiable, so you lose your link to the model variables that produced `sigma`.

In your case, because you state that sigma is either 1 or 0, you can use the value of sigma as a mask, and skip the conditional statement (and even the loop).

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    _, sigma = model(images, training=True)
    predictions = (1.0 - sigma) * binary_classifier_model_a(images, training=False)\
                   + sigma * binary_classifier_model_b(images, training=False)
    loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems solution to your ploblem is to control flow operations. Try using tf.where. You can implement your condition by doing something like this.

```
a = tf.constant([1, 1])
b = tf.constant([2, 2])
p = tf.constant([True, False])
x = tf.where(p, a + b, a * b)
```

For more information please refer [this](https://effectivemachinelearning.com/TensorFlow_2.0/4._Control_flow_operations:_conditionals_and_loops)